# How to show an arbitrary line in TMemo in FMX?

Tags: delphi, tmemo, firemonkey-fm2

I add lines to a TMemo in Firemonkey and I want the line added to be scrolled into view when there are more lines than can be displayed in the TMemo. I cannot find how to do that. I tried

```
Display.Lines.Add (arg);
Caret.Line := Display.Lines.Count - 1;
Caret.Pos  := 0;
Display.CaretPosition := Caret;
```

but that did not help. The help was very limited so I am not sure what I am doing here.

**Update**

When trying out the code of the respondents I noticed I had tested the code example wrong. I apologize for that, my only excuse is that it was near midnight when I wrote and tested the code. The code above **does** work. I deleted the statement `Display.CaretVisible := True;` from the original code because this did not impact the behavior I desired.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  Does `display overflows` mean the `TMemo` has more lines than can be displayed without scrolling?  Does `display added line` mean **scroll to the added line when it isn't visible**?  Do you just want to scroll it into view, or do you want to also select the added line?

Comment: I want to scroll the lastly added line into view. Selection is not relevant. Caret is declared as `Caret: TCaretPosition`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are are just appending the string via `Lines.Add()`, you can call `Display.GoToTextEnd` to scroll it to the end and show the just appended line.

Comment: This answer works fine. Both answers work equally well and I am very grateful to Jason and you. I decided to mark your answer as the correct one as you were the first to react. I know this is arbitrary but I simply don't know how to otherwise award the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the value of the VScrollBar.Value property to its Max value.  That will always scroll - or force the scrollbar - to the bottom of the Memo (ScrollBox).

eg:

```
Display.VScrollBar.Value := Display.VScrollBar.Max
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for your comment. See also the comment at James L's answer.